# Installing lattice in R: "Error : Invalid DESCRIPTION file"

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using R 3.0.2 and am trying to install the lattice package, like so:

```
install.packages("lattice")
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Error : Invalid DESCRIPTION file

Invalid Priority field. Packages with priorities 'base' or 'recommended' or 'defunct-base' must already be known to R.
```

How can I fix it?

Since the [DESCRIPTION](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) just seems to contain meta-info, I do not see why this should preclude me from installing the lattice package.

**Update:**

I have lattice installed, but need a newer version due to some dependencies. Using `update.packages()` for lattice returns the same error as above. I wonder if it is possible that the newer lattice versions are not compatible with the new R version?

Seeing BondedDust referring to DESCRIPTION I started investigating it, and it seems the new package has a Priority field in the DESCRIPTION file, but that the old version of the lattice DESCRIPTION file does not. Why should this matter?

```
me@tang:~/test_lattice$ grep Priority /home/endrebak/local/anaconda/lib64/R/library/lattice/DESCRIPTION                                                                                    
me@tang:~/test_lattice$ grep Priority lattice/DESCRIPTION #New version
Priority: recommended
```

I've tried updating the old DESCRIPTION file with a `Priority: recommended` line and reloading R, but still

```
>rownames(installed.packages(priority="recommended"))
NULL
#rownames(installed.packages(priority="base")) works fine, however.
```

Full error message below:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.uib.no/src/contrib/lattice_0.20-29.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 347091 bytes (338 Kb)
* installing *source* package ‘lattice’ ...
** package ‘lattice’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error : Invalid DESCRIPTION file

Invalid Priority field.
Packages with priorities 'base' or 'recommended' or 'defunct-base' must
already be known to R.

See the information on DESCRIPTION files in section 'Creating R
packages' of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘lattice’
* removing ‘/home/me/local/anaconda/lib64/R/library/lattice’
* restoring previous ‘/home/me/local/anaconda/lib64/R/library/lattice’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmptpj1ff/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("lattice") :
  installation of package ‘lattice’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I think lattice is a part of base R, so you should only need to do `library(lattice)`

Comment: After checking, I now think `lattice` is a "recommended" package that will be included with binary files, but not technically part of the base.

Comment: Your first comment was correct as far as what should be needed (and implicitly that installation is not needed.). `lattice` does ship with R and the version 3.0.2 entry of lattice in the .../library/... is  sym-link with no DESCRIPTION file. Same is true of `pkg:survival`

Comment: Try this code: `rownames(installed.packages(priority="recommended") )`

Comment: @BondedDust: that code returned NULL, but rownames(installed.packages()) included lattice.

Comment: @JohnPaul I have lattice installed, but I need to upgrade the version, due to some other dependencies. Trying to install the zoo package returned:

    namespace ‘lattice’ 0.20-24 is being loaded, but >= 0.20.27 is required

Comment: @BondedDust: Thanks for the DESCRIPTION tip. Updated my q with info.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't update to R 3.1?

Comment: I'm working with RPY2, which seems to be a precarious thing. Perhaps I should try upgrading.

Comment: When you ask: " I wonder if it is possible that the newer lattice versions are not compatible with the new R version?" ... you should be asking if newer versions can be compiled with _older_ versions of R, and in general the answer will be _no_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this error by upgrading to R 3.2.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by just deleting the "Priority: recommended" line in the DESCRIPTION file